# Error with Pascal-like custom language compiler construction

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

This is a compiler for a Pascal-like custom language. It works fine until I try to get it to handle restricted globals.

I think the issue is in Block. When I try to compile the custom language code I've included below, it hangs up at the line containing: IF 10=A THEN ELSE WRITE(A,C)

I need the example code to compile with no errors.

Compiler:

```
// ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream> // for handling files
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
// ***********END MODIFIED********************
// -------------------------------------------
// These are some global definitions
// -------------------------------------------
#define TRUE        1
#define FALSE       0

#define MAX_TABLE   500
#define MAX_SYMBOL  47
#define MAX_SYM_SZ  20

// -------------------------------------------
// These are some ERROR definitions
// -------------------------------------------
#define ERROR_SEMICOLON     1
#define ERROR_IDENT         2
#define ERROR_UNKNOWN       3
#define ERROR_ASSIGN        4
#define ERROR_ASSIGN_PROC   5
#define ERROR_PROCEDURE     6
#define ERROR_END_SYM       7
#define ERROR_DO_SYM        8
#define ERROR_THEN_SYM      9
#define ERROR_VARIABLE      10
#define ERROR_RPAREN        11
#define ERROR_IS_PROCEDURE  12
#define ERROR_PROG_SIZE     13
#define ERROR_END_PROG      14
#define ERROR_NUMBER        15
#define ERROR_LPAREN        16
#define ERROR_REL           17
#define ERROR_NUMBER_IDENT  18
#define ERROR_NOPROCEDURE   19
// ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
#define ERROR_UNTIL_SYM     20
#define ERROR_TO_DOWNTO     21
#define ERROR_OF_SYM        22
#define ERROR_COLON         23
#define ERROR_CEND          24
#define ERROR_CONSTANT      25
// ***********END MODIFIED********************

// -------------------------------------------
// some enumerated data types
// -------------------------------------------
typedef enum tag_symbol
{
    VARSYM,
    CONSTSYM,
    BEGINSYM,
    ENDSYM,
    PERIOD,
    SEMICOLON,
    COLON,
    LPAREN,
    RPAREN,
    GRTHEN,
    LSTHEN,
    GREQL,
    LSEQL,
    EQL,
    ASSIGN,
    IFSYM,
    IDENT,
    NUM,
    PROCSYM,
    NOTEQL,
    MINUS,
    PLUS,
    DIV,
    MULT,
    COMMA,
    ODDSYM,
    CALL,
    THENSYM,
    WHILESYM,
    DOSYM,
    // ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
    ELSESYM,
    REPEATSYM,
    UNTILSYM,
    FOR,
    TOSYM,
    DOWNTOSYM,
    CASESYM,
    OFSYM,
    CENDSYM,
    WRITESYM,
    WRITELNSYM
    // ***********END MODIFIED********************
}symbol;

// -------------------------------------------
typedef enum tag_Objtype
{
    NOTYPE,
    CONSTANT,
    VARIABLE,
    PROCEDURE
}Objtype;

typedef enum tag_intype
{
    ALPHA,
    DIGIT,
    EOL,
    NONE,
    PUNCT,
    SPACE
}intype;

// -------------------------------------------
typedef struct tag_symtable    // Symbols Table Structure
{
    char name[MAX_SYM_SZ];     // Symbol name
    Objtype kind;           // Type of symbol
}symtable;

// -------------------------------------------
// These are some global variables
// -------------------------------------------
int  linelength,        // line length
linecount,         // line counter
charcount,         // a character counter
number;

symbol prevsym;         // holds the previous symbol
symtable  table [MAX_TABLE];     // table array
char   line  [MAX_SYM_SZ];      // an identification string
char   punc  [MAX_SYM_SZ];      // punction array
char   symstr[MAX_SYMBOL][MAX_SYM_SZ];  // symbols array

// -------------------------------------------
// These are some function prototypes
// -------------------------------------------
void   block(symbol &, int);
void   statement(symbol &, int);
void   condition(symbol &, int);
void   expression(symbol &, int);
void   term(symbol &, int);
void   factor(symbol &, int);
char   getchar(char   &);
void   getsym(symbol &);
intype chartype(char  ch);
void   enter(Objtype, char[], symbol &, int &, int &);
int    position(int);
void   error(int);

// -------------------------------------------
// This handles our system errors
// -------------------------------------------
void error(int num)
{
    cout << endl;

    switch (num)
    {
        case ERROR_NOPROCEDURE :
            cout << "Procedure not accepted here";
            break;
        case ERROR_NUMBER_IDENT :
            cout << "number or ident expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_ASSIGN :
            cout << "Assignment operator expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_ASSIGN_PROC :
            cout << "Assignment not allowed here";
            break;
        case ERROR_END_PROG :
            cout << "Premature end of program";
            break;
        case ERROR_DO_SYM :
            cout << "DO symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_END_SYM :
            cout << "END symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_IDENT :
            cout << "Identifier Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_IS_PROCEDURE :
            cout << "Assignment to PROCEDURE not allowed";
            break;
        case ERROR_NUMBER :
            cout << "A number was Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_PROG_SIZE :
            cout << "Program size is too large...";
            break;
        case ERROR_RPAREN :
            cout << "RIGHT Parenthesis Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_LPAREN :
            cout << "LEFT Parenthesis Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_SEMICOLON :
            cout << "Semicolon Expected" ;
            break;
        case ERROR_THEN_SYM :
            cout << "THEN symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_UNKNOWN :
            cout << "Unknown Identifier";
            break;
        case ERROR_VARIABLE :
            cout << "Variable or Expression Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_REL :
            cout << "Relational operator expected";
            break;
            // ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
        case ERROR_UNTIL_SYM:
            cout << "UNTIL symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_TO_DOWNTO:
            cout << "to or downto Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_OF_SYM:
            cout << "OF symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_COLON:
            cout << "COLON Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_CEND:
            std::cout << "CEND symbol Expected";
            break;
        case ERROR_CONSTANT:
            std::cout << "Constant expected";
            break;
            // ***********END MODIFIED********************
    }
    cout << endl;
    exit(1);
}

// -------------------------------------------
// Insert Block Identifier
// -------------------------------------------
void enter(Objtype kind, char name[], symbol &sym, int &tableinx)
{
    tableinx++;
    strcpy(table[tableinx].name, name);
    table[tableinx].kind = kind;

    if (kind == CONSTANT)
    {
        if (sym != IDENT)
            error(ERROR_IDENT);
        getsym(sym);
        if (sym != EQL)
            error(ERROR_ASSIGN);
        getsym(sym);
        if (sym != NUM)
            error(ERROR_NUMBER);
        getsym(sym);
    }
    else if (kind == VARIABLE)
    {
        if (sym != IDENT)
            error(ERROR_IDENT);
        getsym(sym);
    }
    else if (kind == PROCEDURE)
        getsym(sym);
}

// -------------------------------------------
// Locate Position
// -------------------------------------------
int position(int tableinx)
{
    int i = tableinx;

    for (strcpy(table[0].name, line); strcmp(table[i].name, line) != 0; i--);

    return i;
}

// -------------------------------------------
// Block
// -------------------------------------------
void block(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    while (sym == CONSTSYM || sym == VARSYM) {
        if (sym == CONSTSYM)
        {
            // ---- CONSTANT SYM ----
            getsym(sym);
            enter(CONSTANT, line, sym, tableinx);

            while (sym == COMMA)
            {
                getsym(sym);
                enter(CONSTANT, line, sym, tableinx);
            }
            if (sym != SEMICOLON)
                error(ERROR_SEMICOLON);
            getsym(sym);
        }
        // ---- VARIABLE SYM ----
        if (sym == VARSYM)
        {
            getsym(sym);
            enter(VARIABLE, line, sym, tableinx);
            while (sym == COMMA)
            {
                getsym(sym);
                enter(VARIABLE, line, sym, tableinx);
            }
            if (sym != SEMICOLON)
                error(ERROR_SEMICOLON);
            getsym(sym);
        }
        // ---- PROCEDURE SYM ----
        while (sym == PROCSYM)
        {
                getsym(sym);
                if (sym != IDENT)
                    error(ERROR_IDENT);
                enter(PROCEDURE, line, sym, tableinx);
                getsym(sym);

                block(sym, tableinx);//inc static link for functions inside of functions, table current pointer

                if (sym != SEMICOLON)
                    error(ERROR_SEMICOLON);
                getsym(sym);
        }
    }

    statement(sym, tableinx);

}

// -------------------------------------------
// Statement
// -------------------------------------------
void statement(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    int i;

    switch (sym)
    {
            // IDENT
        case IDENT:
            i = position(tableinx);
            if (i == 0)
                error(ERROR_UNKNOWN);

            switch (table[i].kind)
        {
            case VARIABLE:
                getsym(sym);
                if (sym != ASSIGN)
                    error(ERROR_ASSIGN);
                getsym(sym);
                expression(sym, tableinx);
                break;

            default:
                error(ERROR_ASSIGN_PROC);
        }
            break;

            // PROCEDURE CALL
        case CALL:
            getsym(sym);

            if (sym != IDENT)
                error(ERROR_IDENT);

            i = position(tableinx);
            if (i == 0)
                error(ERROR_UNKNOWN);

            if (table[i].kind != PROCEDURE)
                error(ERROR_PROCEDURE);

            getsym(sym);
            break;

            // BEGIN and END block
        case BEGINSYM:
            getsym(sym);
            statement(sym, tableinx);
            while (sym == SEMICOLON)
            {
                getsym(sym);
                statement(sym, tableinx);
            }
            if (sym != ENDSYM)
                error(ERROR_END_SYM);
            getsym(sym);
            break;

            // WHILE SYMBOL
        case WHILESYM:
            getsym(sym);
            condition(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != DOSYM)
                error(ERROR_DO_SYM);
            getsym(sym);
            statement(sym, tableinx);
            break;

            // IF - THEN - ***ELSE***
        case IFSYM:
            getsym(sym);
            condition(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != THENSYM)
                error(ERROR_THEN_SYM);
            getsym(sym);
            statement(sym, tableinx);
            // ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
            if (sym == ELSESYM)
            {
                getsym(sym);
                statement(sym, tableinx);
            }
            // ***********END MODIFIED********************
            break;

            // ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
        case REPEATSYM:
            do {
                getsym(sym);
                statement(sym, tableinx);
            } while (sym == SEMICOLON);
            if (sym != UNTILSYM)
                error(ERROR_UNTIL_SYM);
            getsym(sym);
            condition(sym, tableinx);
            break;

        case FOR:
            getsym(sym);
            if (sym != IDENT)
            {
                error(ERROR_IDENT);
            }
            i = position(tableinx);
            if (i == 0)
                error(ERROR_VARIABLE);
            if (table[i].kind != VARIABLE)
                error(ERROR_VARIABLE);
            getsym(sym);
            if (sym != ASSIGN)
            {
                error(ERROR_ASSIGN);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            expression(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != TOSYM && sym != DOWNTOSYM)
            {
                error(ERROR_TO_DOWNTO);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            expression(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != DOSYM)
            {
                error(ERROR_DO_SYM);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            statement(sym, tableinx);
            break;

        case CASESYM:
            getsym(sym);
            //i = position(tableinx);
            expression(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != OFSYM)
            {
                error(ERROR_OF_SYM);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            while (sym == NUM || sym == IDENT)
            {
                if (sym == IDENT){
                    i = position(tableinx);
                    if (i == 0)
                        error(ERROR_VARIABLE);
                    if (table[i].kind != CONSTANT)
                        error(ERROR_CONSTANT);
                }
                getsym(sym);
                if (sym != COLON)
                {
                    error(ERROR_COLON);
                }
                getsym(sym);
                statement(sym, tableinx);
                if (sym != SEMICOLON)
                {
                    error(ERROR_SEMICOLON);
                }
                getsym(sym);
            }
            if (sym != CENDSYM)
            {
                error(ERROR_CEND);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            break;

        case WRITESYM:
            getsym(sym);
            if (sym != LPAREN)
            {
                error(ERROR_LPAREN);
            }
            do
            {
                getsym(sym);
                expression(sym, tableinx);
            } while (sym == COMMA);
            if (sym != RPAREN)
            {
                error(ERROR_RPAREN);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            break;

        case WRITELNSYM:
            getsym(sym);
            if (sym != LPAREN)
            {
                error(ERROR_LPAREN);
            }
            do
            {
                getsym(sym);
                expression(sym, tableinx);
            } while (sym == COMMA);
            if (sym != RPAREN)
            {
                error(ERROR_RPAREN);
            }
            getsym(sym);
            break;
            // ***********END MODIFIED********************
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------
// Condition
// -------------------------------------------
void condition(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    // ODD symbol
    if (sym == ODDSYM)
    {
        getsym(sym);
        expression(sym, tableinx);
    }
    else
    {
        expression(sym, tableinx);
        if ((sym == EQL) || (sym == NOTEQL) || (sym == LSTHEN) || (sym == LSEQL) || (sym == GRTHEN) || (sym == GREQL))
        {
            getsym(sym);
            expression(sym, tableinx);
        }
        else
            error(ERROR_REL);
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------
// Expression
// -------------------------------------------
void expression(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    if ((sym == PLUS) || (sym == MINUS))
    {
        getsym(sym);
        term(sym, tableinx);
    }
    else
        term(sym, tableinx);

    while (sym == PLUS || sym == MINUS)
    {
        getsym(sym);
        term(sym, tableinx);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------
// TERM
// -------------------------------------------
void term(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    factor(sym, tableinx);
    while ((sym == MULT) || (sym == DIV))
    {
        getsym(sym);
        factor(sym, tableinx);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------
// FACTOR
// -------------------------------------------
void factor(symbol &sym, int tableinx)
{
    int i;

    switch (sym)
    {
            // IDENTIFER
        case IDENT:
            i = position(tableinx);
            if (i == 0)
                error(ERROR_UNKNOWN);
            if (table[i].kind == PROCEDURE)
                error(ERROR_IS_PROCEDURE);
            getsym(sym);
            break;

            // NUMBER
        case NUM:
            getsym(sym);
            break;

            // LEFT PARENTHESE
        case LPAREN:
            getsym(sym);
            expression(sym, tableinx);
            if (sym != RPAREN)
                error(ERROR_RPAREN);
            getsym(sym);
            break;
        default:
            error(ERROR_VARIABLE);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------
// This is our GET CHARACTER function
// -------------------------------------------
char getchar(char &ch)
{
    static char line[255];           // local array
    if (charcount == linelength)
    {
        charcount = linelength = 0;       // zero out counters
        cin.get(ch);
        while (chartype(ch) != EOL && cin)
        {
            line[linelength] = ch;
            cin.get(ch);
            linelength++;
        }
        if (linelength == 0 && charcount == 0 && !cin)
            error(ERROR_END_PROG);

        line[linelength] = 0;
        cout << line << endl;

        line[linelength] = ' ';
        linecount++;                    // count lines
        linelength++;                   //
    }
    ch = toupper(line[charcount]);
    charcount++;                      // count characters
    return ch;
}

// -------------------------------------------
// This is our GETSYM
// -------------------------------------------
void getsym(symbol &sym)
{
    char ch;
    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        getchar(ch);
    } while (chartype(ch) == SPACE || chartype(ch) == EOL);

    if (chartype(ch) == ALPHA)
    {
        do
        {
            line[index++] = ch;
            getchar(ch);
        }
        while (chartype(ch) == ALPHA || chartype(ch) == DIGIT || ch  == '_');
        line[index] = '\0';
        charcount--;
        if (strcmp(line, "BEGIN") == 0)
            sym = BEGINSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "CALL") == 0)
            sym = CALL;
        else if (strcmp(line, "CONST") == 0)
            sym = CONSTSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "DO") == 0)
            sym = DOSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "END") == 0)
            sym = ENDSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "IF") == 0)
            sym = IFSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "ODD") == 0)
            sym = ODDSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "PROCEDURE") == 0)
            sym = PROCSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "THEN") == 0)
            sym = THENSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "VAR") == 0)
            sym = VARSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "WHILE") == 0)
            sym = WHILESYM;
        // ***********BEGIN MODIFIED******************
        else if (strcmp(line, "ELSE") == 0)
            sym = ELSESYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "REPEAT") == 0)
            sym = REPEATSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "UNTIL") == 0)
            sym = UNTILSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "FOR") == 0)
            sym = FOR;
        else if (strcmp(line, "TO") == 0)
            sym = TOSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "DOWNTO") == 0)
            sym = DOWNTOSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "CASE") == 0)
            sym = CASESYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "OF") == 0)
            sym = OFSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "CEND") == 0)
            sym = CENDSYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "WRITE") == 0)
            sym = WRITESYM;
        else if (strcmp(line, "WRITELN") == 0)
            sym = WRITELNSYM;
        // ***********END MODIFIED********************
        else
        {
            sym = IDENT;
            strcpy(symstr[sym], line);
        }

        return;
    }

    if (chartype(ch) == DIGIT)
    {
        char strnum[10];
        sym = NUM;
        number = 0;
        do
        {
            strnum[index++] = ch;
            number = 10 * number + int(ch - 48);
            getchar(ch);
        } while (chartype(ch) == DIGIT);
        charcount--;
        strnum[index] = '\0';
        strcpy(symstr[sym], strnum);

        return;
    }

    if (chartype(ch) == PUNCT)
    {
        punc[index++] = ch;
        if (ch == ':' || ch == '<' || ch == '>')
        {
            getchar(ch);
            if (chartype(ch) == PUNCT && (ch == '=') || (ch == '>'))
                punc[index++] = ch;
            else
                charcount--;
        }

        punc[index] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(punc, ":=") == 0)
            sym = ASSIGN;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ":") == 0)
            sym = COLON;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ",") == 0)
            sym = COMMA;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "/") == 0)
            sym = DIV;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "=") == 0)
            sym = EQL;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ">=") == 0)
            sym = GREQL;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ">") == 0)
            sym = GRTHEN;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "(") == 0)
            sym = LPAREN;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "<=") == 0)
            sym = LSEQL;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "<") == 0)
            sym = LSTHEN;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "-") == 0)
            sym = MINUS;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "*") == 0)
            sym = MULT;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "<>") == 0)
            sym = NOTEQL;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ".") == 0)
            sym = PERIOD;
        else if (strcmp(punc, "+") == 0)
            sym = PLUS;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ")") == 0)
            sym = RPAREN;
        else if (strcmp(punc, ";") == 0)
            sym = SEMICOLON;

        strcpy(symstr[sym], punc);

        return;
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------
// determine a character type
// -------------------------------------------
intype chartype(char ch)
{
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
        return EOL;        // character END-OF-LINE
    if (isspace(ch))
        return SPACE;      // character SPACE
    if (isdigit(ch))
        return DIGIT;      // character DIGIT
    if (isalpha(ch))
        return ALPHA;      // character ALPHA
    if (ispunct(ch))
        return PUNCT;      // character PUNCTUATION

    return NONE;
}

// -------------------------------------------
// This is our main program entry
// -------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    symbol sym;
    int i;
    char filen[40];

    // Initialize some variables
    linelength = 0;
    charcount  = 0;
    linecount  = 0;

    getsym(sym);                  // get the first symbol
    block(sym, 0);                  // start processing

    cout << "\nSuccessful compilation!\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Custom code that does not compile correctly (should compile with no errors):

```
CONST
        A=10;
VAR
        B,C;

PROCEDURE TWO;
VAR
        A2,B2;
BEGIN
        A2:=1;
        REPEAT
                WRITELN(A2);
                A2:=A2+1;
        UNTIL A2>=3;
        REPEAT
              B2:=1;
                    REPEAT
                          WRITELN(A2,B2);
                          B2:=B2+2;
                    UNTIL B2>A2;
              A2:=A2+1
        UNTIL A2>5;
END;

VAR
        M;
PROCEDURE ONE;
CONST
        A=5;
VAR
        B1,C1,D1;
BEGIN
        M:=30;
        CALL TWO;
        FOR B1:=1 TO A DO
         FOR C1:=1 TO B1 DO
          WRITELN(B1,C1,B1*C1);
         FOR B1:=10 DOWNTO A DO
          WRITE(B1);
         FOR B1:=10 TO A DO
          WRITELN(B1);
         FOR B1:=1 TO C DO
          BEGIN
           C:=C+1;
           WRITELN(B1,C)
          END
END;
VAR
        STATE;
BEGIN
        B:=11+A*(A-A);
        FOR C:=1-A+A TO B+1 DO
            CASE C+1 OF
             3:WRITELN(A,B,C);
             A:IF A+1=B THEN
                IF 10=A THEN ELSE WRITE(A,C)
               ELSE WRITE(B,C);
             11:IF A+B=3 THEN
                 IF 10=A THEN WRITELN(A,C)
                 ELSE
                ELSE WRITELN(B,C);
            CEND;
        STATE :=0;
        REPEAT
              CASE STATE+1 OF
                   1:BEGIN
                          WRITE(1);
                          STATE:=2
                     END;
                   2:WRITELN(2);
                   3:BEGIN
                      WRITELN(STATE+3);
                      STATE:=4
                     END;
                   4:WRITELN(STATE*4);
              CEND
        UNTIL STATE=4;
        C:=4;
        CALL ONE;
END.
```

Comment: You'll need to modify `statement` to allow an empty statement.

Comment: I added `default: break;` to `statement`, but I still have the same issue.